# How to add a new NOTE with an existing CONTACT in ANDROID

Tags: android

i successfully updated the existing NOTE in a contact using 
getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);

this method doesn't work for adding a new NOTE..
How to add a new NOTE with an existing CONTACT in ANDROID?

Comment: you have to insert the note element, not update it

Answer (score 1):

```
public void testInsert()
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    // insert a empty note into RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, and get the rawContactId
    Uri rawContactUri = this.getContext().getContentResolver().insert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, values);
    // get id
    long rawContactId = ContentUris.parseId(rawContactUri);
    // insert name data
    values.clear();
    values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId); // id
    values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);// MIMETYPE
    values.put(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, "zetsin");// first name
    this.getContext().getContentResolver().insert(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
    // insert phone
    values.clear();
    values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
    values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    values.put(Phone.NUMBER, "123456");
    values.put(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_MOBILE);
    this.getContext().getContentResolver().insert(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
    // insert email
    values.clear();
    values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
    values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    values.put(Email.DATA, "zetsin@gmail.com");
    values.put(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_WORK);
    this.getContext().getContentResolver().insert(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```